# Send image from c++ server to Android client

Tags: android, c++, image

I have on my C++ server an image saved as blob in a sqlite database. I take these image from database like this:

```
        int sizeForThumbnail = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStmt, 1);
        char* thumbnail = (char * )sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStmt,1);
```

After this i send it to the Android phone using a socket connection:

```
        write(clientDescriptor,thumbnail,sizeForThumbnail);
```

On the Android phone i try to get the image like this:

```
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[65536];
        int countForBytes = in.read(byteBuffer,0,65536);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteBuffer, 0, countForBytes);
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now i read exactly how much i send from the c++ server. `countForBytes` is equal with `sizeForThumbnail` but `decodeByteArray()` returns null. What am i doing wrong? After i get the image from database i tried to write `thumbnail` in a file and save it as `jpeg` format and it gets the correct image so the retrieval from the database is correct.

Comment: How many bytes is your image? If it is less than 65536 it is already consumed from the inputstream at the first br.read(). So it would be completely in buffer. You try to overwrite buffer in following read(). What is exactly send by first write() ? How many chars? And is there a separation char between that length and the image bytes? Does the client know how many bytes it should read first to determine the size?

Comment: `i tried to write thumbnail in a file and save it as jpeg format and it gets the correct image so the retrieval from the database is correct.`. You should let the client do the same. So you can check.

Comment: It is difficult to believe that `countForSize` is equal `sizeForThumbnail` as you send also a length string.

Comment: the first read and the second one are in different functions so they are independent and `countForBytes` is same as sizeForThumbnail which is the number of bytes read from the second `read()`

Comment: I second the magic @vanekjar discovered already.

Comment: it can be possible that the bytes which are received in the Android device are not the same as the bytes i send from c++?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the magic you are trying to do with the Java code. Why do you store input data in `char` and then in `String`.

What about decoding the bitmap directly from `InputStream`. Will it work for you?

```java
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I tried this way but `bmp` is also null..i used the string for something else, is not very important

Comment: do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Did you throw away the part with the sending of data length? Send just the image data for this test. Could you modify your question for me to see how the code looks like now?

Comment: Have you tried with another image? Maybe this one is somehow corrupted. Maybe it's in CMYK colorspace or something.